# Issue with passing gzip commpressed JSON file in Postman PUT Request - 400 Bad Request - Meraki API

Tags: json, postman, gzip

I am trying to send compressed JSON in gzip format in a PUT request in Postman, but I get a 400 Bad Request error.

I am trying to send a PUT request via Postman to Meraki API and because my request body is so large I end up getting a 502 bad gateway error as I believe I am hitting some hard size limit. This led me to try gzipping my JSON request body and sending it as a binary file in Postman.

Every time I try to send I get a "400 Bad Request: There was a problem in the JSON you submitted" error. If I decompress the JSON and just send the JSON file itself I get the 502 error so I know it's not an error with my decompressed JSON, something about when I gzip it seems to malform it in such a way that Postman can no longer understand it.

As far as headers go I am using:

```
content-type:application/json
```

There is also a hidden header Postman adds:

```
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate
```

An example of the decompressed JSON:

```
{
    "updateAction": "add",
    "tags": "TestTag",
    "wifiMacs": "80:EE:73:C6:C0:4B,80:EE:73:C5:D6:6F,80:EE:73:C6:C0:00,80:EE:73:CB:14:A6,80:EE:73:CB:12:36,80:EE:73:DC:6F:27,80:EE:73:DC:74:73,80:EE:73:DE:41:AE,80:EE:73:DE:41:A0,80:EE:73:DC:75:18,80:EE:73:DA:7A:2B,80:EE:73:DA:7C:F2,80:EE:73:DE:42:7A"
}
```

I should get an HTTP 200 OK response

Answer (score 0):

'content-type' header only identifies the type of content you're sending (json/xml/text etc). Compression is something you apply *on the raw content* you're trying to send and that needs to be indicated separately. For this to work, you would need to add an extra header:

> content-encoding: gzip